# passing objects between jsf and jpa

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jpa

How can I emulate this behaviour

```
             <h:selectOneMenu id="idMovie" value="#{comments.comments.idMovie}" title="IdMovie" required="true" requiredMessage="The idMovie field is required." >
                <f:selectItems value="#{movies.movieItemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:selectOneMenu id="idUser" value="#{comments.comments.idUser}" title="IdUser" required="true" requiredMessage="The idUser field is required." >
                <f:selectItems value="#{user.userItemsAvailableSelectOne}"/>
            </h:selectOneMenu>
```

In a way such as

```
            <h:SOMETHING id="idMovie" ´valueToCommit´="#{comments.comments.idMovie}" ´valueToGet´="#{movies.movies}"/>


            <h:SOMETHING id="idUser" ´valueToCommit´="#{comments.comments.idUser}" ´valueToGet´="#{user.userSession.user}"/>
```

movies.movie has the current object I need 
and so does user.userSession.user, but I don't know how to pass them to comments.commment.idMovie (which is of type Movie) to get committed

Thanks in advance

best regards
ignacio

Comment: How is JS related to this question? And, are you using JSF2 or not? You should tag as such.

Comment: Just edited question sorry, yes JSF 2.0

Comment: What happend with the answer?

Comment: My answer concerned Facelets. But after all you was using JSP instead of Facelets, in spite of that you're using JSF 2.0. So I deleted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in the constructor of commentController;

```
    userController = (UserController) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{user}", UserController.class);
    movieController = (MovieController) facesContext.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(facesContext, "#{movie}", MoviesController.class);
```

Plus (in the declaration)

```
private MovieController movieController = null;
private Comment comment = null;
private UserController userController = null;
```

and

```
public String create() {
    try {
        utx.begin();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        Exception transactionException = null;
        comment.setUserId(userController.getUser());
        comment.setMovieId(movieController.getMovie());
        jpaController.create(comment); ...Default Facade class
        try {
            utx.commit();
        } catch (javax.transaction.RollbackException ex) {
            transactionException = ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }...
          ...
```

Did the trick!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If both are just `@ManagedBean`, then `@ManagedProperty` is nicer than this `evaluateExpressionGet()`.

Comment: I'm not sure no how to apply said change.